# How can I get the Scala compiler to infer the type of this function?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I have a function that I can't get type inference to work on. Full sample code is below, but the function in question is this:

```
def mapObjects[T, S <: HasGetter[T]](lst: GenSeq[S]): GenSeq[T] = {
  lst map {v => v.getT}
}
```

The problem is that calling mapObjects requires naming types T and S explicitly. Is there a way to write this function's type signature so that inference works correctly?

Working sample code:

```
import scala.collection.GenSeq

trait HasGetter[T] {
  def getT: T
}

class HasStringGetter(str: String) extends HasGetter[String] {
  override def getT = str
}

object TypeInferenceTest {
  def mapObjects[T, S <: HasGetter[T]](lst: GenSeq[S]): GenSeq[T] = {
    lst map {v => v.getT}
  }

  def tst {
    val objs = List(new HasStringGetter("abc"), new HasStringGetter("def"), new HasStringGetter("hij"))

    // Doesn't typecheck
    // val strs = mapObjects(objs)

    val strs = mapObjects[String, HasStringGetter](objs)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just:

```
def mapObjects[T](lst: GenSeq[HasGetter[T]]): GenSeq[T] = {
    lst map {v => v.getT}
  }

scala> mapObjects(objs)
res18: scala.collection.GenSeq[String] = List(abc, def, hij)
```

There is no real advantage of using `S <: HasGetter[T]` in your case as you are just doing a map over `lst` and obtaining elements of type `T`. And your return type of the function has got nothing to with type `S`. Hence there is no need to get the precise type `S`

Had the return type of the function or function body explicitly needed to maintain the type `S <: HasGetter[T]`, your code would be needed. But in this case there is no point maintaining the type.

Moreover `GenSeq[+A]` is a covariant type. So by default it can accept types belonging to `GenSeq[ <: HasGetter[_]]` in the argument. Has `GenSeq` not been co-variant, it would have been a different Issue.

Comment: Thanks - your comment about GenSeq[+A] being a covariant type lit a light bulb: HasGetter[T] can be HasGetter[+T]. Not naming S at all is also insightful and helped with a different function. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sam Depends on what `HasGetter` was made for, to decide if it should be covariant or invariant. In short co-variance suits where you have to read data and contra-variance when you have to write. I had written a blog on it: http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/co-variance-contra-variance/ and http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/continuation/